# How to make a site's menu stick to the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am using [this code](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/06/24/creating-a-swipeable-side-menu-for-the-web/) for this side menu in my site, exactly as explained in the link. I don't know how to change it so that the menu sticks to the top of the screen when you scroll.

This is for that you don't have to scroll all the way back up to click on the menu again.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [position: fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Where would I insert this?

Comment: You haven't posted any code so how could I possibly know? My previous comment was also a link BYT

Comment: Think he's coming back?

Comment: @WilliamRose Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

will keep your menubar at the top when you scroll.

To go along with the comments you posted. Say you have

```
<div class="menubar"> menubar</div>
```

around all of your menubar, find that class in your CSS file. and add my answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

When placing the following CSS properties on a element (which is the menu in this case)

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

It will stay "fixed" at the top of the page or parent element you have placed it in.

For positioning it further you can use the the `right`, `left` and `bottom` properties.

More about the `position` property can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

---

Example:

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <p>Some menu text</p>
  <p>Some menu text</p>
</div>

<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
<H1>Some Header text</H1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use this in your "css" for the menubar Tag.

```
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

will keep your menubar at the top at all times.

Check out this link.
http://sixrevisions.com/css/fixed-navigation-bar/